# Mark Private Option is not available in contact form of user in lotus notes Why?

Tags: lotus-notes, contact-form

In Lotus Notes Client I have logged in using admin account and accessing all other users using Open Other Contacts Option. In Contact form of admin account i am able to see Mark Private Option but for all other users, contact form i am not able to see Mark Private Option why ?

[image: Admin User Contact Form]

[image: Other User Contact Form]

Answer (score 2):

Because auf the hide when
Owner := @GetProfileField("CalendarProfile"; "Owner");
@LowerCase(Owner) !=  @LowerCase(@UserName)
If you are not the owner of a mail file or addressbook, you are not allowed to mark contacts private...

Comment: And this is a logical consequence because the way it is solved: the "Mark privat" works with a reader field... and if you would allow someone else to set it, the document would disappear either for the owner or for the user who sets the flag...

Comment: I'm guessing that this question really belonged over on SuperUser or ServerFault, but one of the great things about Notes is that a lot of user and admin questions can be answered by developers looking at the templates.

Comment: So, If I want to Mark Contacts under the Test user as private, then I want to login lotus notes using Test user credential?

Comment: You could always set these things with lotusscript. Just analyze the template and try to find out what happens if the field is checked. What and how the other fields are set ..